# Barcode not showing in browser Oracle Reports 11g

Tags: oraclereports

In the report builder have assign IDautomation 39 barcode fount.
after reinstall the server barcode not showing in browser.

I have install Idautomation 39 fount on server machine and client machines
but failed to showing barcode.